# red circle will not disappear, onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, variables

red circle will not disappear 
Definition and Usage
The onclick event occurs when the user clicks on an element.

*Technical Details
Bubbles:    Yes
Cancelable: Yes
Event type: MouseEvent
Supported HTML tags:    All HTML elements, EXCEPT: , , 
, , , , , , , , and 
DOM Version:    Level 2 Events*

```
<head>

<title>Javascript</title>

<style type="text/css">

.circle {

width: 120px; 
height: 120px;
border-radius:50%;
float:left; 
margin-right:50px;

}

#red-circle {

background-color: red;

}

#blue-circle {

background-color: blue;

}

#yellow-circle {

background-color: yellow;

}

    </style>

    </head>

<body>

<div class="circle" id="red-circle"></div>

<div class="circle" id="blue-circle"></div>

<div class="circle" id="yellow-circle"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    documnet.getElementById("red-circle").onclick = function() {

        document.getElementById("red-circle").style.display = "none";

    }


    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: `documnet` !== `document`

Comment: documnet.getElementById("red-circle") document miss spelled

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
 documnet.getElementById("red-circle").onclick = function() {
```

`documnet` instead of `document`. Just run it and check console.

Comment: In this case the Question should be closed as Off-Topic.